# gcc compile instruction contain flag -03. What does it do?

Tags: gcc

https://stackoverflow.com/a/71366629/15603477

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -std=c17 read_stdin_fgets_basic_input_from_user.c -o bin/a && bin/a
```

The whole line I don't understand **-03** part. But I don't think compiler have this flag. S what does it do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`-O` flag is for optimize](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) and takes various arguments, with `-O3` meaning "optimize yet more", beyond what `-O1` or `-O2` do. There is also `-Os` to reduce code size, and other flags to disable optimization, or to optimize for debugging.

Comment: Care should be taken with these global flags since they might not impact identically across versions.